# How to call REST API and parse XML Structure?

Tags: web-services, api, xml-parsing

I am new to Android Programming.
I want to use a RESTful Webservice for my android app where I will be calling a REST API and in response I want to parse the XML Structure, consume the XML tag values and show it in UI.
Can anybody guide me with the required steps and some sample code.
Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

You should glance at [Retrofit](http://square.github.io/retrofit/).
Retrofit helps you to hook up with a server in a very elegant way.

By default, Retrofit expects JSON data but you can set it up to use XML, via the Simple library.

Comment: Thanks a lot :)
But as I am a beginner, I was looking for more simpler and straight forward approach in doing this.